# Parse Cloud function with Query (promise issue)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've got a cloud function that is supposed to run a Jar file on the server and then fetch some data from the db. This is what I have for now:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('search', function(req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req))
  runjar(req.params.searchTerms[0]).then(resp => {
    getids(JSON.stringify(resp)).then(resp => {
      console.log("getids output = " + resp)
      res.success(resp)
    });
  });
});

const runjar = function(searchInputString) {
  const util = require('util');
  const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
  return exec('java -jar -Xms1024m all.jar ' + searchInputString).then(resp => {
    const string = resp.stdout;
    var regex = /(\d+)=(\d+)/g;
    var matches = getMatches(string, regex, 1);
    console.log(string);
    return matches
  });
}

const getids = function(idArray) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("collection1");
    query.containedIn('identifier', idArray);
    query.limit(10);
    return query.find().then(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        status.success(results);
        return result;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        status.error(error)
        return Parse.Promise.error(error);
    });
}
```

I method gets stuck in the getids function, which does not return any data! I tried using a separate query, like the following, but I get the same empty array.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
  var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var Product = Parse.Object.extend("collection1");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Product);
    query.equalTo("identifier", 309255);
    query.first().then(function(result){
        if(result){
            // If result was defined, the object with this objectID was found
            promise.resolve(result);
        } else {
            console.log("Product ID: " + productId + " was not found");
            promise.resolve(null);
        }
    }, function(error){
            console.error("Error searching for Product with id: " + productId + " Error: " + error);
            promise.error(error);
    });

    return promise;
});
```

Comment: Can you please paste your console logs here? I guess you need to remove status.success(results); and status.error(error). I don't see where the var "status" is defined.

Comment: The console.log inside the query.find() method never get called

Comment: neither this one? console.log(JSON.stringify(req))

Comment: For the "test" function, use response.success() instead of promise.resolve() and response.error() instead of promise.error()